# Redirect all subdomains to a new domain with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I am trying to redirect all subdomains to a new domain with htaccess.

1. All subdomains with any path get forwarded:

   y.domain.com/anything --> y.domain2.com/anything
2. Don't forward the main domain or www:

   domain.com --> domain.com

   www.domain.com --> www.domain.com

I have tried the following but does not seem to be working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain2.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change or completely clear browser cache.